# [antd]How to change webpack-dev-server http to https in dva or roadhog

Tags: antd

[I want to know how to configure https in roadhog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTzfz.png)

Comment: add your code what you have done for it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This community is about helping each other, but you are expected to make an effort yourself before asking questions. This question is showing no effort on your part to solve the issue. Tell us what attempts and research you have done so far and you will have a greater chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the doc: [https://github.com/sorrycc/roadhog#环境变量](https://github.com/sorrycc/roadhog#%E7%8E%AF%E5%A2%83%E5%8F%98%E9%87%8F)

> OS X, Linux

**HTTPS=true roadhog server**

> Windows (cmd.exe)

**set HTTPS=true&&roadhog server**